# "Boyfriend" and "girlfriend" usage

Tags: word-usage

Why is it customary for a heterosexual woman to refer to her heterosexual female friend as a "girlfriend",but not the case for a heterosexual man and his male buddy to call one another "boyfriends"?
How did our language evolve this way,and is it similar in other languages throughout the world?

Comment: I have no idea how it evolved that way, sorry, I look forward to our hearing together from those who do. I have observed that the words for "lover" are ambiguous in lots of languages. My Cameroonian girlfriend  has just joined me at the computer and asked what I am doing. She says she would call her same-sex friend her "copine", and that if she lives with me three months she becomes, not my "(petite-)amie" but my "concubine". (TBC)

Comment: (Continued)  In Norwegian, my second language, _venn_ and _vennine_ are desperately ambiguous, but they have the option of using _kamerat_ (borrowed from German). There again, any female Anglo keen to avoid the implication of lesbianism can use _pal_, can she not? (I have used _gal-pal_ myself, although by rights it does not belong to my generation or segment.) In Hebrew, _khaver_, originally "comrade" as in the early-communist usage, by at least the Seventies came to mean one's main squeeze. I think _amiga_ is ambiguous, but don't have a Spaniard on tap at the moment.

Comment: Non-English languages are out of scope, but culture must play a part. Where homosexuality is illegal, for example, boyfriend may be used between heterosexual men simply because a homosexual use is unthinkable. (There are English-speaking cultures where homosexual practices are illegal, so this part does appear to be in-scope.)

Comment: @Andrew: Remember E.M. Forster's dictum about betraying his country before betraying his friend? He's surely talking about his lover.

Comment: I don't claim to know the history either. There are lots of things in language that don't have a good logical reason: they just are. @andrewleach In the U.S., women were calling female friends "girlfriends" while men were not calling male friends "boyfriends" for as long as I can remember, way back when homosexuality here was, if not illegal, at least much more frowned on that it is today.

Comment: @DavidPugh The word "concubine" is used when discussing cultures where polygamy is practiced to mean a lesser wife of inferior status to the man's "primary" wife or wives. To me it sounds like a demeaning thing to call a woman, like, "You're not high class enough to be my wife, but I'd take you as a concubine." :-)

Comment: @Jay, in English, agreed, and I wouldn't use it. I thought it was clear that I was talking about _Franco-African_ usage. Here, your primary wife is called your _titulaire_, whether you like it or not.

Comment: Curiously girlfriend meaning female friend is older in usage than man's sweetheart.  *Girlfriend also girl-friend, by 1859 as "a woman's female friend in youth," from girl + friend (n.). As a man's sweetheart, by 1922. She-friend was used 17c. in the same set of senses, of the mistress of a man and of a woman who is a close friend of another.* (Etymonline)

Comment: @DavidPugh Oh, I thought you were saying she called herself that in English. Of course words can have different connotations in different times and places even when we are nominally speaking the same language. Connotations in a different language might well have little relation.

Comment: Straight women speaking of "Girlfriends" is an American usage thing IMO which in Britain would still raise eyebrows .

Comment: @the other one: And particularly, I think, when "Girlfriend" is used between women as a _term of address_. Which, funnily enough, it is not between man and woman. I should think that a British woman addressed as "Girlfriend" would raise an eyebrow and diagnose an detox clinic – for Lena Dunham? Sex & the Shopping? Something like that, I am no expert.

Comment: I'll just point out that _mate_ is used some varieties of English to denote a man's male friend despite its alternative meaning of a sexual partner. But I'd guess the boyfriend/girlfriend asymmetry is just the result of boy/girl asymmetry, women are called girls more regularly than men are called boys.

Comment: I have male friends but I cannot (because it feels weird) and do not call them *boyfriends*, I simply call them *friends* likewise with my female friends. I don't use the term *girlfriend* referring to someone in their 50s, that's a bit odd. You have *mates*; *pals*, *buddies* these are all terms that do not carry romantic connotations. *girlfriend*, and *boyfriend* have sexual and romantic connotations, because evidently there is an expressed  need for terms that express romantic relationships between two people who aren't married.

Comment: I suspect the difference is just a reflection of the sexism that has existed in our culture for centuries, and results in many gender biases in language (like words with the _man_ root being used to refer to people in general).

Comment: Neil- true that mate has an odd meaning between men as compared to between parrots (for example).Though that is really a human/animal thing IMO. You would never hear people speak of their significant others being 'mates' in the mating sense! Any attempt to do so would likely result in a slap!

Answer (score 2):

I think the following extract offers an interesting point of view on the subject:

A [Lexical](http://dialectblog.com/2011/09/25/boyfriend-and-girlfriend/) Beef: ‘Boyfriend’ and ‘Girlfriend.

> - Etymology Online dates the term ***“[boyfriend](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=boyfriend&searchmode=none),” meaning “woman’s paramour,” to 1909. However, the term has an earlier platonic sense.***  The first use I managed to find in Google Books, from an obscure 1850 publication titled Friends’ review: a religious, literary and miscellaneous journal, describes the friend of a young man, not the lover of a young woman:
> - Though daily occupied with his drudgery as a farm servant, he began to instruct himself in Latin and Greek. A boy friend lent him several books necessary in these studies…
> - ***[Girlfriend](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Girlfriend&searchmode=none) seems to have had a similar trajectory, beginning as a term for a young female friend, only taking on romantic connotations after the conversion of boyfriend.***  Intriguingly, the original sense of girlfriend is still alive and kicking, as one can hear in phrases like, “I’m going to spend some time with my girlfriends this weekend.”  I can’t say for sure why the platonic meaning of boyfriend didn’t also survive.  ***Perhaps some consider it un-masculine to refer to your drinking buddies the same way their girlfriends do?***

(dialectblog.com)